# How to make an isProduction()-function in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing tests that will run on both a dev-environment and on a prod-environment.

I can see that the [Cypress-documentaion discourages anti-patterns and conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html).

However... I can't really see how I can avoid this here? As an example:

On the **dev-environment**, i want these tests that `noindex` is **enabled** on all pages.
On the **prod-environment**, i want these tests `noindex` is **disabled** on all pages

---

### So how would I achieve this?

**Solution A - Make tests for each environment**

Make a folder called 'Tests-for-dev' and a folder called 'Tests-for-prod'. However... many of these tests would be almost identical. So it would quite the hassle maintaining tests in those folders.

Another problem, if doing this is, that if I do this, that the environment-specific tests might have to run after something else. Example:

- 1. Check login (run on prod + dev)
- 2. Ensure noindex is enabled (run on dev)
- 3. Ensure noindex is disabled (run on prod)
- 4. Test purchase (run on prod + dev).

... This seems clumbsy.

---

**Solution B - Conditional testing**

[This would go against the documentations recommendations](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html).

But if I do this:

```
before( () => {
  cy.location()
    .then( (loc) => {
      cy.wrap( loc.hostname ).as( 'hostname' );
    });
});

it( 'Conditional test', () => {

  cy.get( '@hostname' )
    .then( (hostname) => {
      if( hostname === 'staging' ){
        cy.log( 'Dev!' );
        // Enable noindex
      }

      if( hostname === 'production' ){
        cy.log( 'Prod!' );
        // Disable noindex
      }
    });

});
```

Then this works. But it goes against the guiding words of the documentation.

---

### Bonus-question

Are there a way there I can make a global function, so I in all my tests I can write:

```
it( 'Some test', () => {

  if( isProd() ){
    // Do something productiony
  }

  if( ! isProd() ){
    // Do something developpy
  }

});
```

... I tried using commands. But due to the asynchronious nature, then I don't know if they have resolved when using it. I also considered setting something in the Cypress.json-file. But ideally I want a function that checks the hostname and returns a boolean accordingly. So I can ensure that I don't mess up the production-site by forgetting to change a variable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - testing in production is the worst idea you can have and it is better to make a dedicated test server that runs the tests on regular bases, before putting your code in production. But if you insist - here is a solution that you can use to change the tests depending on the environment.

You can set a [Environment value](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting), that is set up for one value in local testing and for another in production and do the test accordingly.

In config.env.json:

```
{
     "baseUrl": "localHostUrl"
}
```

And in tests

```
context( 'Test according to development or production' , function () {
    it( 'Order with DateTime DOES NOT exists', () => {
        if (Cypress.env("baseUrl") === "localHostUrl") {
            // Code for testing locally
        } else if (Cypress.env("baseUrl") === "testServerUrl") {
            //Code for testServer
        }
        else {
            // Code for testing in production
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. Some things can obviously be tested on a dedicated test server. But I assume that some testing should be done on the production environment, to actually check that it works. Right?

Comment: I have seen very funny situation from testing in production, that at the least can ruin the product reputation and at most - ruin you site by for example scrambling your database. In Our team we have manual tester for that part that knows exactly when and what to test. 

But After all - that is our team policy - I do not say it is the best thing, but there is a reason it is highly not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I thought of Rosen's solution and up voted it when I read it, however since I have multiple team members and I want to differentiate between different local and online test environments I figured I can use OS level env variables by setting one like this `export cypress_environment='baha_local'` before running cypress and in the test I can check like this: `Cypress.env('environment')`.

Note: I tried `cypress_env` alone but I got undefined.

[Refrence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_).